# Entity Framework Code First - Specify server to use but not the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use EF CF to create multiple databases using the same schema. I want the flexibility to be able to specify which server I want my database created in, and specify the database name during runtime.

So, in sum, given a server, I want to be able to specify what database to create (or use existing) in runtime. AFAIK, using the connection string forces me to specify the database as well, so that's not good.

Answer (score 0):

A more thorough search came up with this, and it works just as I needed.

Add this to the configuration file

```
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> 
    <parameters> 
      <parameter value="Data Source=MyDatabaseServer; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" /> 
    </parameters> 
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
```

where "MyDatabaseServer" could be your ".\SQLEXPRESS" instance, or whatever.